# Node JS REst API not responding

Tags: node.js, azure, iis, deployment

I am new to Node JS Web API development. I have deployed my REst API on Windows IIS server under the port 81..I have not published it on default port 80 as there are other ASP.net services already published. My API is accessible locally. But, when I try to access it from outside, it goes into hang mode..What to do..?? I am stucked in it since 7 days.

Comment: What do you mean by hang mode? Does the service freeze or the client timeouts because the port is not open on the firewall?

Comment: Port is being already open on Firewall..It is giving error after 30 seconds "This site can’t be reached. Wizapp.in took too long to respond."

Comment: If the API is still available internally, then it is a network error. If not the firewall then what?

Comment: Yes, API is accessible via localhost:81\webreg\users ...Where 81 is the port open for this API..How can it be blocked via the network? I really fail to understand ..That's what I am looking for and it's shocking, not a single solution is available on Google or StackOverflow..

Comment: Maybe you have multiple firewalls involved. Not sure what you mean externally. If you want to access it from the internet, then you need to open port on both the local computers firewall and on your router and do port forwarding to the local computer from the router. Though your local computer can be hacked through the nodejs application if it contains security vulnerabilities, so it always involves risks when you publish an application to the internet.

Comment: Externally means only from the internet outside the local network..My API is hosted on Azure Cloud server ..I just have hosted it through IISNode and URLRewrite extensions..

Comment: Then I think you need somebody who has experience with Azure. I changed the tags, maybe somebody shows up.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Azure..Because Our company has purchased space from Azure for the development and publishing of our apps ourselves..

Comment: If you publish it on an Azure server, then it has something to do with Azure. I would ask their support how to do this or why it doesn't it work. And I would try it with an ASP.NET dummy application first on the same port to know for certain that it is not nodejs related.

Comment: ACtually I am not publishing on Azure Server .. I am publishing NodeJS App on IIS Server on which already many ASP.Net Web apps and Services are already published and running..

Comment: I added IIS to the tags too. If you don't get an answer try it here https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/iis or here https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/iis too. SO is more about programming, these stackexchange sites are more about sysadmin stuff especially the serverfault.